# Get File Size information of File Requested in Download

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

Is there a way to query the size of a file that was requested via http in objective c on iphone.
I would like to find out file size prior to data being sent back so I can write a simple Download Progress indicator.
Your help is much appreciated.
Tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The download size is in the HTTP header "Content-Length"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NSURLConnection to do the download, you can implement connection:didReceiveResponse: in your delegate. When this method is called, you'll be passed an NSURLResponse object that you can call expectedContentLength on.

If you're not using NSURLConnection, you might want to give us a few more details.